# How do I connect/share between my two computers at home and my printer?

Tags: printing, file-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is a CUPS server and how to share a printer over a network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73367/what-is-a-cups-server-and-how-to-share-a-printer-over-a-network)

I have a desktop PC with Ubuntu 11.10 (32-bit) with a Brother MFC printer/scanner connected to it. The desktop is connected to the internet via LAN line. I also have a netbook that is used in the living room also with 11.10 (32-bit). The netbook connects to the internet via Wifi.

How can I set it up so I can print to the printer with the netbook, without having to connect it to the printer in the other room or using google cloud printer?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your exact setup, but this will get you going in the right direction, if you get stuck just update your question. You need to enable printer sharing:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

In this case the computer connected to the printer will be the "Ubuntu print server", so just follow the directions in that part of the document.

> 1. On the server machine (the one the printer is attached to), open System -> Administration -> Printing. This will open the Printer
>      Configuration window. OR you can open the following URL in your
>      browser: http://localhost:631
> 2. Select Server in the menu bar, and then Settings. This will open the Basic Server Settings window.
>
>    1. Check the second box: Publish shared printers connected to this server
> 3. If this computer acts as both a Print Server and a client (it does need access to a printer connected to another computer), select also
>      the first box, "Show printers shared by other systems".

After that just right click on the printer and select "Shared":

[image]