# Printer shared via Ubuntu stops being visible after restart of server machine or client machine

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, printing, samba

I have setup CUPS and Samba server on linux machine which has a hp deskjet 6122 printer attached via usb.
I have also managed to install this shared printer on other windows 7 machine via LAN network.

I have gone through many instructions. These are just few of them:

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/cups.html

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

[What is CUPS server and how to share a printer (Locally or over a network)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73367/what-is-a-cups-server-and-how-to-share-a-printer-over-a-network)

[Sharing Printer with CUPS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100528/sharing-printer-with-cups)

The reason I keep doing the same thing with different instructions is because the whole setup works fine until a restart of the windows machine (client) or linux machine (server with attached printer). After the restart of any machine, sending a print request from the windows machine results in print task being visibile in print queue on windows but NOT visible in the print queue on linux. Obviously, this means that documents are not being printed from windows machine.

This problem drives me mad for weeks.

The only way to print from windows is to repeat procedure of installing the network printer. And it works.... till restart of any machine. Note that I do not have to setup anything on linux again to make windows->linux printing work.

I am begging for advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is consequence of an [very old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/upstart/+bug/494141) in CUPS.

So to fix this, just edit the file `/etc/init/smbd.conf`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/init/smbd.conf
```

Then replace the line:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up)
```

For this:

```
start on (local-filesystems and started cups and net-device-up)
```

I have successful in Ubuntu Saucy (13.10).