# How can I print a file using a printer connected to a different machine on the same LAN

Tags: networking, printing

What's the simplest/best way to print files from any local machine, using a printer connected to only one of them.

Comment: see also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19694/what-is-needed-for-a-networked-home-printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the printer on the system it's connected to, then share it.

This has already been covered on askubuntu before:

[What is CUPS server and how to share a printer (Locally or over a network)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73367/what-is-a-cups-server-and-how-to-share-a-printer-over-a-network)

Also there's a community wiki document on how to share a printer on Ubuntu, and how to connect to printers shared from other OSes from Ubuntu  : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Printers#Sharing_Printers.