# how do I publish a printer

Tags: printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a CUPS server and how to share a printer over a network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73367/what-is-a-cups-server-and-how-to-share-a-printer-over-a-network)

I am trying to publish a printer in 12.10 so I can share via samba.  In the printer properties, it shows "not publishes, see server settings.  I cannot find the server settings.

Comment: Answer can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73367/what-is-a-cups-server-and-how-to-share-a-printer-over-a-network

Answer (score 0):

Open the dash and type Printers, then click on the "Printers" icon.
That will open up a window that will probably have a list of printers.
Move your cursor to the top of the screen to make the context menu show up, and click "Server" -> "Settings".
That will bring up the server settings window, where you can check the box labeled "publish shared printers connected to this system".

edit: or go here for the answer [What is CUPS server and how to share a printer (Locally or over a network)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73367/what-is-a-cups-server-and-how-to-share-a-printer-over-a-network)

Comment: Where is this "Server" -> "Settings"? What program is it? it is not `system-config-printer`, is it?