# Error Message when selecting Printers-Server-Settings

Tags: server, printing

I followed the detailed instructions in the post at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73367/what-is-a-cups-server-and-how-to-share-a-printer-over-a-network) by Luis Alvarado which explained in detail how to share a printer in Ubuntu 12.04.

Everything worked as it was supposed to after following the directions.

My problem is, when I go back to Printers-Server-Settings, I get the following dialog;

CUPS server error
There was an HTTP error: Not found.

Printing still seems to be working but if I want to stop the print server for this printer, how do I reverse the settings I turned on if I can't get to them?

In case it matters, this installation of Ubuntu has HPLIP 3.14.6 installed on.  I assume CUPS is also installed since I see a webpage show up if I go to `http://localhost:631`.  I believe it said 1.53 I think.

I am new to Linux so if any other info is needed, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Thanks for any and all help.

Dan

Comment: Do you mean running Printing and then choosing Server-> Settings?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear.  Yes, I went to the Gear icon in upper right, then selected Printers (I believe that is what it was called - I could also find the same by going to the Gear then selecting System Properties I think and then selecting Printers) and from here went to the upper left of the screen where it showed Printing I think.  This displayed 2 menus, one being Server.  Under this Server menu is where I found the Settings.  When I try to open this menu item, this is where I am now getting the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well; from what I've seen it is a recent problem with CUPS that will be patched soon. In the meantime, I was able to do everything I needed by:

1) Pointing my browser at `localhost:631`, this will bring up CUPS' web interface.
2) Clicking the 'administration' tab. this will give you the ability to edit all options found in printers-server-settings.

Comment: 808style,

Thanks very much for this tidbit of info.  I appreciate it very much.  Since I don't much at all about Linux, what I can't find when doing a search, I turn to folks like you to enlighten me.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Here's the bug report for Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/1349387