# Use ubuntu so windows can print to an unsupported printer

Tags: 14.04, windows, printing

I currently have an HP Laserjet 1012 connected to Ubuntu. It is not supported by windows anymore. I tried to print to it from windows but that does not work. I've been using Google Cloud print as a workaround, but this is less than ideal.

How can I share this printer so windows will actually print to it?

The notes on SAMBA don't help since I think what I really need is to make windows think its printing to something else. The printer IS shared, but there is not a working driver for Win10.

Notes: I'm on Win10 64, and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Printer is shared via SAMBA.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu?action=show&redirect=Samba%2FPrinterSharing

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is CUPS server and how to share a printer (Locally or over a network)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73367/what-is-cups-server-and-how-to-share-a-printer-locally-or-over-a-network)

Comment: I can see the printer from windows. It even tries to install the driver, but it hasn't been officially supported since XP and the workarounds don't work on Win10.

Comment: I think an option will be to upload files to Ubuntu and setup a script there that will pick the uploaded files and print them.

Comment: How about [Google Cloud Print](http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/)?

Comment: I'm using Google Cloud print. That works OK, but it can't be automated, always launches browser to select print options, etc.  Uploading files to Ubuntu + script would require doing everything via PDF.

Comment: You can do the [Cloud Printer Driver](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudprintdriver) that is a local setup so that you can print directly that way.

Comment: I use Dropbox, and have directories for each of my 6 printer queues, plus a half-hourly cronjob. I can "print" from any device that can reach Dropbox.

Comment: I think you can enable support for ipp in windows 10. If so you can directly print to this printer using cups

Answer (score 1):

I use Dropbox, and have directories for each of my 6 printer queues, plus a half-hourly cronjob. I can "print" from any device that can reach Dropbox.

But, for a locally connected system, you could manage CUPS from `http://localhost:631`, click on the `Administration` tab, and Enable Printer Sharing and a couple of others. Here is what I have: [image: Administration buttons]

First, of course, is to ensure that CUPS is working on the system where the printer is connected.

Second is to convince Windows to print to a "Generic Postscript Printer/Network Printer". GLWT (Good Luck With That)